# invalid syntax when run pylint

Tags: python

the following is the stack trace, please suggest
my python version is 2.7

```
-----------------
pylint
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python27\Scripts\pylint-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pylint==2.0.0', 'console_scripts', 'pylint')()
  File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pylint-2.0.0-py2.7.egg\pylint\__init__.py"
, line 17, in run_pylint
    from pylint.lint import Run
  File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pylint-2.0.0-py2.7.egg\pylint\lint.py", li
ne 75, in <module>
    import astroid
  File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\astroid-2.0.1-py2.7.egg\astroid\__init__.p
y", line 59, in <module>
    from astroid.exceptions import *
  File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\astroid-2.0.1-py2.7.egg\astroid\exceptions
.py", line 13, in <module>
    from astroid import util
  File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\astroid-2.0.1-py2.7.egg\astroid\util.py",
line 148
    yield from islice(iterator, size)
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

1. my python version is 2.7

Comment: `yield from islice(iterator, size)`, I believe you are running code meant for Python 3. You seem to be running that in Python 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`pylint`](https://pypi.org/project/pylint/) 2.0.0 requires at least Python 3.4.<sup>1</sup>

The last version that supported Python 2.7 was [1.9.2](https://pypi.org/project/pylint/1.9.2/). So, your fix is to downgrade to 1.9.2.

---

The specific error message you're seeing is because `yield from` was added to the language in Python 3.3, so code that uses it can't run in 2.7. But there are probably lots of other errors. After all, the only reason developers drop 2.7 support is so they can use new language features.

---

If you install it with `pip install pylint` or `py -m pip install pylint` using Python 2, it *should* automatically install 1.9.2 instead of 2.0.0—or, failing that, the installation should fail instead of appearing to succeed. (When I test it myself, that's exactly what happens.)

However, installing with an old version of `pip`, might cause this problem. If so, upgrade your `pip` and `setuptools`. (You definitely want at least `pip` 10 and `setuptools` 30… but generally you want the latest version available, so just let it do that.)

```
py -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
```

If that was your problem, you should have seen a warning, like `You are using pip version 6.0, however version 18.0 is available.` That warning doesn't look hugely important, but it is—especially if you're staying on 2.7 (or, similarly, if you like to follow the bleeding edge and install beta versions of Python).

Installing with `easy_install` can definitely cause this. If that's your problem, just stop using `easy_install` and start using `pip`.

If you installed it manually instead of by using `pip`, then you have to do the version checking manually as well. If you have a good reason for doing that, download 1.9.2 and install that manually instead.

---

At any rate, however you got thing into this situation, you should be able to fix it by uninstalling `pylint` and then running:

```
py -m pip install pylint==1.9.2
```

---

<sub>1. According to its own documentation, it specifically supports 3.4, 3.5, and 3.6. It may also support 3.7 despite saying it doesn't—later versions definitely do, and of course future versions will support even newer versions of Python. But definitely not 2.7.</sub>

Comment: It's possible the OP installed pylint using an older version of pip (pre-9.0, I believe) that doesn't support `Requires-Python`.  That would have gotten them into this situation.

Comment: @jwodder Yeah, I was trying to find which version that was added in… but I settled for just saying at least version 10.

Comment: @abarnert thanks a lot. python -m pip install pylint==1.9.2 sloved this issue.

Comment: The first statement is not correct, pylint 2.0, the released version, supports Python 3.7.

Comment: @PCManticore No, [2.0](https://pypi.org/project/pylint/2.0.0/) did not support 3.7 yet. The versions listed are 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, and there’s a note at the bottom of the description saying for 3.7 support you need to install the preview version. Of course that no longer matters, because 2.0 isn’t the current version anymore, and 2.1 does support 3.7. (And neither 2.0 nor 2:1 nor any future version will work with 2.7, which is what the OP needs.)

Comment: @abarnert Nope, 2.0, at the time of release, had support for Python 3.7, and this is coming from someone who actually released the thing. I know this is not what the OP needs, but I need to clarify this situation, since it might be confusing for other folks as well.

Comment: @PCManticore Then why does 2.0.0 say 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, and have a "Note Python 3.7 support is currently available on the preview release: `pip install pylint astroid --pre -U`" at the end of the description? And why does 2.0.1 have the same note? If that's all wrong, it seems like that's where the confusion comes from. But at any rate, I don't think anyone is going to be confused here. Anyone doing a `pip install pylint` is going to get 2.1.1 or later, and anyone who explicitly asks for `pylint==2.0.0` presumably knows what they're doing and has a good reason.

Comment: @PCManticore At any rate, I've moved whatever confusion there is into a footnote and changed the first sentence to say "at least Python 3.4".